# FlipClock.js is incrementing seconds by 2

Tags: flipclock

Interesting behavior in FlipClock library (http://flipclockjs.com/)

The following code works fine:

```
        clock1 = $('.clock1').FlipClock( {
            clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock'
        });
```

However, if you include an adjustment for timezone, then it starts incrementing seconds by 2:

```
        clock1 = $('.clock1').FlipClock(3600 * 3, {
            clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock'
        });
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't see the API description for your second usage at that web site. What version are you using?

Comment: Hi Bob, just downloaded a few days ago, so should be newest. You are correct, I could not easily find in the API doc how to accomplish this, so I winged it by copying from another example. If you could point me to the API doc point on the correct way to do this, that would be great!

Comment: I followed the link you gave in your OP. From there, there are several collections of documentation, including the developer's API. As I said, I could not find the usage you are using.